# event handler is missing once a function is called in js script

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, printing

I have written some js code to print an image on click of an anchor tag in page's html.on first when document is loaded and i click the function it prints the image
but when i cancel the print from browser print print preview it take me to my webpage , now second time if i click on print anchor tag, it does not work and event listener is not showing that js script i written which works fine first time.
Below is my code to print the image.

```js
(function ($) {
  "use strict";

  function printDiv(imglink){
    var originalContents=document.body.innerHTML;
     var printContents = '<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-3824" src="'+imglink+'" />';
     // var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
     document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
     document.bgColor = '#ffffff';

     window.print();
     document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
    
  } 
  
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var plink=$('div.printit').children()[0];
    plink.removeAttribute('href');
    var hostname=window.location.hostname;
    var port=window.location.port;
    // var imglink=$('div.field--name-field-healthpass-image').children()[0].src;
    var imglink='http://'+hostname+':'+port+'/themes/child/images/massage-voucher.jpg';
    $(plink).on("click",printDiv(imglink));
  });
  
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: $(plink).on("click",printDiv.bind(null,imglink))

Comment: `document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;` - that removes event listeners

Comment: I think you can use css @media query for print, just hide all content using@ meida css {display: none} except the content which you want to print and fire js event: window.print();  demo is here: http://codepen.io/ashraftalib/pen/Jbygpw/

Answer (score 0):

You can either use an anonymous callback function or you can use `event.data` object to pass the data:

```
(function($) {
  "use strict";

  function printDiv(event) {
    var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
    var printContents = '<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-3824" src="' + 
                         event.data.imglink + '" />';
    // var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
    document.bgColor = '#ffffff';

    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;

  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    var plink = $('div.printit').children()[0];
    plink.removeAttribute('href');
    var hostname = window.location.hostname;
    var port = window.location.port;
    // var imglink=$('div.field--name-field-healthpass-image').children()[0].src;
    var imglink = 'http://' + hostname + ':' + port + '/themes/child/images/massage-voucher.jpg';
    $(plink).on("click", {imglink:imglink}, printDiv); // <---here
  });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: problem is that when i store orignal content to document body, it loses event listener,,, first time node prints by my written function i successfully passed the image to winodw print, but second time my script does not work because i placed orignal contents in disc 
-> document.body.innerHTML=orignalcontents;
here something happens and event is not binding to control again

Comment: That is what happens when you replace all the contents, it removes the event listeners, so you have to rebind it again.